# how can I use encodeFunctionCall()?

Tags: web3js

my function has component(structure) parameter.

```
{
        "inputs": [
            {
                "components": [
                    {
                        "internalType": "uint32",
                        "name": "total",
                        "type": "uint32"
                    },
                    {
                        "internalType": "uint32",
                        "name": "times0",
                        "type": "uint32"
                    },
                    ...
                ],
                "internalType": "struct Ticket.PackInfo",
                "name": "_packInfo",
                "type": "tuple"
            }
        ],
        "name": "createTicket",
        "outputs": [],
        "stateMutability": "payable",
        "type": "function"
    }
```

it's abi.

I want to make transaction.
so I need to use web3.eth.abi.encodeFunctionCall()

```
data = web3.eth.abi.encodeFunctionCall({name:'createTicket', type:'function, input:})
```

What expression should I put in input ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

The `parameters` argument accepts an array of function arguments.

When an argument is a `struct`, you need wrap its values in another array and sort them in the order according to the order of the struct properties.

```
const parameters = [
    [100, 200] // <total>, <times0>
];

const data = web3.eth.abi.encodeFunctionCall(abiJson, parameters);
console.log(data);
```

Comment: thanks soo much!